# extracting source url and the anchor text in a string

Tags: php

I am trying to extract data from a series of string but no luck.
in the example code below, I tried using preg_split but its not giving me the result I want.

using the code below:

```
<?php
$str = '<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008EYEYBA" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Nike Air Jordan SC-2 Mens Basketball Shoes 454050-035</a><img src="http://www.assoc-amazon.com/e/ir?t=mytwitterpage-20&l=as2&o=1&a=B008EYEYBA" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
';
$chars = preg_split('/ /', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($chars);
echo '<pre>';
?>
```

gives the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008EYEYBA" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Nike
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Air
            [1] => 167
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jordan
            [1] => 171
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => SC-2
            [1] => 178
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mens
            [1] => 183
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Basketball
            [1] => 188
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Shoes
            [1] => 199
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 454050-035 205
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => src="http://www.assoc-amazon.com/e/ir?t=mytwitterpage-20&l=as2&o=1&a=B008EYEYBA"
            [1] => 224
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => width="1"
            [1] => 305
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => height="1"
            [1] => 315
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => border="0"
            [1] => 326
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => alt=""
            [1] => 337
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => style="border:none
            [1] => 344
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => !important;
            [1] => 363
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => margin:0px
            [1] => 375
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => !important;"
            [1] => 386
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => />

            [1] => 399
        )

)
```

note in array1, the word "Nike is included when I only need is just the URL.

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008EYEYBA" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Nike
            [1] => 3
        )
```

actually, my ultimate goal in extracting $str is just to output the source URL and the achor text in a separate array like so:

**URL:**

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008EYEYBA/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B008EYEYBA&linkCode=as2&tag=mytwitterpage-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008EYEYBA)

**anchor text:**

Nike Air Jordan SC-2 Mens Basketball Shoes 454050-035

any idea how I can accomplish this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression to parse html is a bad practice. PHP has [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension for that. You simply cannot build a universal regex which is going to work for any html you might encounter. DOM approach is much more extendable.

```
$string = '<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008EYEYBA">Nike Air Jordan SC-2 Mens Basketball Shoes 454050-035</a><img src="http://www.assoc-amazon.com/e/ir?t=mytwitterpage-20&l=as2&o=1&a=B008EYEYBA" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($string);
libxml_clear_errors();
$elementA = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
$aText = $elementA->nodeValue;
$aLink = $elementA->getAttribute('href');
echo $aLink . "\n" . $aText;
```

Comment: i tried this and its giving me Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 1 in

Comment: Thats because only a piece of the whole document is proveded. You can mute the warnings or provide a full document.

Comment: btw,i tried it with an img tag and i cant seem to grab the img url. <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008EYEYBA/ref=as_li_ss_il?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B008EYEYBA&linkCode=as2&tag=mytwitterpage-20"><img border="0" src="http://ws.assoc-amazon.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B008EYEYBA&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=US&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=mytwitterpage-20" ></a><img src="http://www.assoc-amazon.com/e/ir?t=mytwitterpage-20&l=as2&o=1&a=B008EYEYBA" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />

Comment: `$elementImg = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0); $imgLink = $elementImg->getAttribute('src');` Should work.

Comment: Thank him by upvoting, not by commenting!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the help of php function.

You want to remove the anchor tag here.

you can use strip_tags() function to remove all tags.

Comment: thanks webduos, that works but only giving me the anchor text. how about the source URL? any built-in function that can give me just the URL same as the strip_tags() does with the anchor text?